# AccuRev merge shows zero differences?

Tags: accurev

facing really unusual error while resolving overlap, when merge is clicked below warning message is prompt.

C:\Program Files (x86)\AccuRev\bin\diff3.exe: diff.exe --horizon-lines=100 -- D:\plt_tf_dev_new\database\oracle\server\update26\update_dml_common_26.sql "C:\Users\TPATHR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\anc3693382490409658896.tmp"

after clicking "ok", merge window shows zero differences causing difficulty in resolving merge.
tried uninstalling & installing AccuRev, same error is prompted gradually.

Comment: Perhaps that means the merge is resolved with no changes. What error?

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this down a bit by attempting to merge a different file. Preferably one that is a different file extension. Second, check that the path to the temporary file is valid. Specifically, see what happens if you either run "dir" or "cd" into "C:\Users\TPATHR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\". Third, if the temporary file still exists, and this may be a long shot, try running the exact command that you see in the warning message:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\AccuRev\bin\diff3.exe: diff.exe --horizon-lines=100 -- D:\plt_tf_dev_new\database\oracle\server\update26\update_dml_common_26.sql "C:\Users\TPATHR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\anc3693382490409658896.tmp"
```

Lastly, try to run an "accurev merge" command from CLI within the directory where the overlapped file is located. Often, CLI will give better errors and warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Run Accurev as Administrator. It will work fine.